# Use a set command in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, def

To make the plots easier, I define commands using `\def` which I then use in the figures.
I would like to define `\def` for `coordinate` but when I compile, I have the error: Use of \focale doesn't match its definition

My code :

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def \focale{5}
\def \focale2{2}
\def \lentille{2.75}

\coordinate (O) at (\focale,-\lentille);%centre optique de la première lentille
\coordinate (A) at (\focale,0);%position de l'objet
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can not use number in command names. Use `focaleii`, for example.

Answer (score 4):

The problem in your code is explained by [@Sigur's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/671166/use-a-set-command-in-tikz/671175#comment1668195_671166).

I suggest you use [the `declare function`](https://tikz.dev/math-algorithms#pgf/declare:function) key of the mathematical engine, which you can also use to define constants that are correctly evaluated in all places where Ti*k*Z expects an expression.

```latex
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function = {
        focale = 5;
        focale2 = 2;
        lentille = 2.75;
    }
    ]
\coordinate (O) at (focale,-lentille);%centre optique de la première lentille
\coordinate (A) at (focale,0);%position de l'objet
\draw (O)--(A);
\coordinate (O2) at (focale2,-lentille);%centre optique de la première lentille
\coordinate (A2) at (focale2,0);%position de l'objet
\draw[red] (O2)--(A2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I used the definition local to the picture, but you can also put it in a `\tikzset` and make it global (with the usual scoping of TeX).